# Port in use when launching Node.js app with Heroku Foreman

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

I am trying to deploy my node.js app to heroku but when I try to launch it locally using foreman I am  getting Error: listen EADDRINUSE. I have run a netstat and grepped for the port nothing else is using it and the server starts without issue when running directly as a node http server.

The app I am trying to deploy is using mongo and redis I am not sure if these components will effect the server starting with Foreman. Does anyone have any suggestions on areas I could look at for potential bugs?

```
foreman start
01:37:18 web.1  | started with pid 1835
01:37:18 web.1  | /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:66: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
01:37:19 web.1  | events.js:72
01:37:19 web.1  |         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
01:37:19 web.1  |               ^
01:37:19 web.1  | Error: listen EADDRINUSE
01:37:19 web.1  |     at errnoException (net.js:863:11)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1008:14)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at listen (net.js:1030:10)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Server.listen (net.js:1096:5)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Function.app.listen (/Users/craig/Documents/Sandboxes   /xxx/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:535:24)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/craig/Documents/Sandboxes/xxx/web.js:25:5)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
01:37:19 web.1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
01:37:19 web.1  | exited with code 8
01:37:19 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Thanks.

--Additional information--

The procfile just has one entry:
    web: node web.js

and I have set the listener up as follows:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to start your HTTP server on an specific port? (note that you should use `process.env.PORT` as the port number whenever you want to start an HTTP server on [tag:heroku])

Comment: Please post your Procfile and node.ks app config

Comment: Please find the additional details requested above in the original post

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this on OS X. It looks like foreman picks port 5000 by default, which seems to conflict with Bonjour/mDNS/UPNP services. (From what I've read. I haven't taken the time to pick out which it is.)

However, you can change the port that foreman uses in two ways: [specify the port on the command line](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#RUNNING) or [create a .foreman file with the port number specified there](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#DEFAULT-OPTIONS).

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Daniel is right. For example this worked for me:  foreman start -p 8000  So I ended up specifying the port number and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` means that a Node server is already running.

Check that you are not running a Node server for the same project locally. If you are working on a GitHub synced project locally (on port 5000 for instance) which is tied to Heroku you cannot run a local Node server for that project as the port will be in use twice.

I was actually running a Node server on a project in a different Terminal window and didn't notice immediately.